# How to convert GPS altitude to other vertical reference systems?

Tags: gps, xyz

I have GPS positions with altitude and I would like to convert this altitudes to a local vertical reference system. In my case I would like to convert it to DHHN92 (EPSG 5783). I probably want to convert an elipsodial height to a hight above seelevel.

For conversion of 2D coordinates between reference systems you can use predefined transformations.
Possibly this methods are existing for 3D data too.

How to convert GPS altitude to other vertical reference systems?

Comment: What GIS Tools do you have available?

Comment: The data is stored/processed in a postgis database. Beyond that OSGeo Software like QGIS, Grass, ... is available.